# Get topleft and bottomright points which bound a polyline collection using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone, shapes

So I have a collection of polylines where each contains several Points.

I want to obtain the minimum and maximum X,Y points from those polylines collection so that I can figure out the bounding rectangle that contains the polylines. How do I do this using LINQ?

The polylines are children of a Canvas. In the picture attached, there are three red polylines drawn. The yellow rectangle are imaginary boundary.

```
var polylines = this.CanvasDraw.Children.Cast<Polyline>();
```

I want to do something like

```
        double minX;
        double minY;
        double maxX;
        double maxY;

        foreach (Polyline polyline in polylines)
        {
            foreach (var point in polyline.Points)
            {
                if (point.X is the minimum)
                {
                    minX = point.X;
                }

                 if (point.Y is the minimum)
                {
                    minY = point.Y;
                }

                if (point.X is the maximum)
                {
                    maxX = point.X;
                }

                if (point.Y is the maximum)
                {
                    maxY = point.Y;
                }
            }
        }

Point Topleft = new Point(minX, minY);
Point BottomRight = new Point(maxX, maxY);
```

[image: There are three Polylines on the canvas]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany` to get the points from all the lines into a single collection, then just use `Min()` and `Max()` to pull out the extremes:

```
var polylines = this.CanvasDraw.Children.Cast<Polyline>();

// project all points into a single list
var allPoints = polylines.SelectMany(pl=>pl.Points).ToList();

// get mins and maxes
var minX = allPoints.Min(p=>p.X);
var minY = allPoints.Min(p=>p.Y);
var maxX = allPoints.Max(p=>p.X);
var maxY = allPoints.Max(p=>p.Y);

// create bounding points
Point Topleft = new Point(minX, minY);
Point BottomRight = new Point(maxX, maxY);
```